# Trouble receiving data via HTTP on OpenTelemetry Collector in Docker

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I am working on integrating OpenTelemetry .NET SDK with Elastic APM and am using OpenTelemetry Collector to forward traces and metrics.

My service is running in Docker, and I'm using `otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.91.0` as the collector. I've set up the collector to receive data over both gRPC and HTTP as indicated in the screenshots provided.

Here is the relevant portion of my `otel-collector.yml` for the collector:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: localhost:4317
      http:
        endpoint: localhost:4318

exporters:
    debug:
        verbosity: detailed
    otlphttp:
      endpoint: https://apm-server:8200
      tls:
          insecure: false
          insecure_skip_verify: true
          ca_file: /usr/share/otel-collector/certs/ca/crt.crt
          cert_file: /usr/share/otel-collector/certs/ca/crt.crt
          key_file: /usr/share/otel-collector/certs/ca/crt.key
      headers:
        Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics:
        receivers: [otlp]
        exporters: [debug, otlphttp]
    traces:
        receivers: [otlp]
        exporters: [debug, otlphttp]
    logs:
        receivers: [otlp]
        exporters: [debug, otlphttp]
```

And this is the **`docker-compose.yml`** configuration:

```
  otel-collector:
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.91.0
    container_name: otel-collector
    volumes:
        - ./open-telemetry/otel-collector-config.yml:/etc/otelcol-contrib/config.yaml
        - ./volumes/elk/certs/ca:/usr/share/otel-collector/certs/ca:ro
    ports:
      - "4318:4318"
      - "4317:4317"
    depends_on:
      - apm-server
    environment:
      TOKEN: ${TOKEN}
```

Also, here's a snippet of the .NET SDK configuration:

```
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .ConfigureResource(
        resource =>
        {
            resource.AddTelemetrySdk()
                .AddService("sample");
        })
    .WithMetrics(provider =>
    {
        provider.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
                .AddOtlpExporter(exporter =>
                {
                    exporter.Endpoint = new Uri("http://otel-collector:4318");
                });
    })
    .WithTracing(provider =>
    {
        provider.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
                .AddEntityFrameworkCoreInstrumentation()
                .AddOtlpExporter(exporter =>
                {
                    exporter.Endpoint = new Uri("http://otel-collector:4318");
                });
    });
```

`otel-collector logs`

```
2024-01-18 14:58:04 2024-01-18T12:58:04.283Z    info    service@v0.91.0/telemetry.go:86 Setting up own telemetry...
2024-01-18 14:58:04 2024-01-18T12:58:04.287Z    info    service@v0.91.0/telemetry.go:203        Serving Prometheus metrics      {"address": ":8888", "level": "Basic"}
2024-01-18 14:58:04 2024-01-18T12:58:04.287Z    info    exporter@v0.91.0/exporter.go:275        Development component. May change in the future.        {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "debug"}
2024-01-18 14:58:04 2024-01-18T12:58:04.289Z    info    exporter@v0.91.0/exporter.go:275        Development component. May change in the future.        {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "logs", "name": "debug"}
2024-01-18 14:58:04 2024-01-18T12:58:04.289Z    info    exporter@v0.91.0/exporter.go:275        Development component. May change in the future.        {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "debug"}
2024-01-18 14:58:04 2024-01-18T12:58:04.290Z    info    service@v0.91.0/service.go:145  Starting otelcol-contrib...     {"Version": "0.91.0", "NumCPU": 8}
2024-01-18 14:58:04 2024-01-18T12:58:04.290Z    info    extensions/extensions.go:34     Starting extensions...
2024-01-18 14:58:04 2024-01-18T12:58:04.328Z    info    otlpreceiver@v0.91.0/otlp.go:83 Starting GRPC server    {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "data_type": "traces", "endpoint": "localhost:4317"}
2024-01-18 14:58:04 2024-01-18T12:58:04.331Z    info    otlpreceiver@v0.91.0/otlp.go:101        Starting HTTP server    {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "data_type": "traces", "endpoint": "localhost:4318"}
2024-01-18 14:58:04 2024-01-18T12:58:04.332Z    info    service@v0.91.0/service.go:171  Everything is ready. Begin running and processing data.
```

Why are the data sent via HTTP to port **`4318`** not appearing in the collector's logs, while everything works fine over gRPC on port **`4317`**? I've verified that the ports are open and accessible. What could be the issue?

When I configure the .NET SDK to send data over gRPC to port `4317`, everything works as expected, and I see the data in the collector's logs. However, when I switch the configuration to send data over HTTP to port `4318`, I do not see any data in the logs, even though the logs clearly show that the HTTP server has started and is listening on port `4318`.

Seems the receiver doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Are you sure it should be `localhost` and not `0.0.0.0` in your receiver endpoints ? localhost would just listen to connections coming from the container itself, not other containers in your docker network. (Not sure why that might be different b/w grpc and http though)